# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded | Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have been fighting this error for a bit now, google says it's a loop but I have yet to find a loop in my code. I do know the router is trying to reload and related to the error message because in my Chrome console I get `Token: null` about ~100 times

I've included what I think are the related files and stripped out the unneeded stuff. In my store.js file you will see that I console.log the token as it is passed to the `authUser` mutation, this token is output correctly in my console so no issues of missing token.

**main.js**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.fullPath == '/login' || to.fullPath == '/signup') return next()
  console.log('Token: ',store.state.token)
  if(store.state.token) {
    return next()
  } else {
    return next('/signin')
  }
})

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store,
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

**store.js**

```
state: {
    token: null,
    name: '',
    companyName: ''
  },
mutations: {
    authUser(state, userData) {
      console.log(userData.token)
      state.token = userData.token
    }
  },
actions: {
    tryAutoLogin({commit}) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      if(!token) {return}
      commit('authUser',{
        token
      })
    },
}
```

**App.vue**

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('tryAutoLogin')
    }
```

Comment: doesnt look like its in the code you pasted